# windows 7 ndk in eclipse  Indigo throwing not valid win32

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am having a problem I can run ndk outside of eclipse but not from the workspace folder. I get an error of a missing file.

```
Android NDK: ERROR:jni/Android.mk:QCAR-prebuilt: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that jni/../../../build/lib/armeabi/libQCAR.so exists  or that its path is correct
/cygdrive/c/Users/ALEXDEV/android-ndk-r8b/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:43: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

I am wondering if when I create the android project one of the files isnt copied. But when I run it inside eclipse 
I get this error. I followed this tutorial
http://mobilepearls.com/labs/ndk-builder-in-eclipse/

The error I got when running ndk in eclipse was as follows

```
"C:\Users\ALEXDEV\android-ndk-r8b\ndk-build" (in directory "C:\Users\ALEXDEV\workspace\Image"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

What do you suggest that I did wrong and what method do you propose will fix this problem.

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2

I am following this tutorial

http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin

I am using this upload

Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

Instead of dowloading a package from the link I chose the option add but I used archieve. 
Packages can be downloaded straight from eclipse. Here is the link that I used to download 
the package http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php

I then download this version of the ndk

I got the ndk examples working so the problem is solved.

Comment: After edit, please make it easier to understand what results you get with the old method, and what happens when you follow the new tutorial.

Comment: Or even better, close this question and open another one. I believe we have resolved the subj problem, _not a valid Win32 application_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With ndk r8b, you don't need cygwin at all. Set the build command as **ndk-build.cmd**

Note that your tutorial is outdated. The recent versions of ADT plugin allow you to simply click "add native support" to a Java project.

Comment: could you evaulate. When you say set a build command as ndk-build.cmd where can this setting be located.

Comment: Try to put the full path to ndk-build.cmd in the **Location** field of the custom builder.

Comment: i tried following this tutorial http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin is that correct

Comment: for some reason it went horrible wrong and has underlined all the c code

Comment: What do you mean "underlined"?

Comment: they are underlined in red I updated my answer showing a new tutorial that I followed. it uses the installation of the plugin

Comment: First you should verify your setup. The easy way to go is to take one of NDK samples. Note that the tutorial is not for Windows. On Windows, use **ndk-build.cmd** where they use **ndk-build**.

Comment: Thanks man. You save my life. Facing the same issue. By mistake selected bdk-build file instead of ndk-build,cmd